# Python Import Module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, python-import

I know this has been asked dozens of times but I can't see what in the world I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to import a module in python 2.7 from a different directory. I would greatly appreciate some input to help me understand why this method doesn't work. I have the following directory structure on my raspbian system:

```
/home/pi/
        ...projects/__init__.py
        ...projects/humid_temp.py

        ...python_utilities/__init.py__
        ...python_utilities/tools.py
```

I'm calling humid_temp.py and I need to import a function within tools.py This is what their contents look like:

humid_temp.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('home/pi/python_utilities')
print sys.path
from python_utilities.tools import *
```

tools.py:

```
def tail(file):
    #function contents
    return stuff
```

The print `sys.path` output contains */home/pi/python_utilities*

I'm not messing up my `__init__.py`'s am I?
I've also ruled out possible permission issues with that path as I gave it full 777 access and I still hit the

> ImportError: No module named python_utilities.tools.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to import something like -

```
from python_utilities.tools import *
```

You need to add the parent directory of `python_utilities` to `sys.path` , not `python_utilities` itself. So, you should add something like -

```
sys.path.append('/home/pi')       #Assuming the missing of `/` at start was not a copy/paste mistake
```

---

Also, just a note, `from <module> import *` is bad , you should consider only importing the required items, you can check the question - [Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad) - for more details.

Answer (score 2):

In humid_temp.py, just write:

```
from python_utilities import tools
```

There is no need for appending subfolder to sys.path.

Then when you want to use functions from tools, just

```
tools.function()
```